# vb enabler doesn't work in autocad 2010

Tags: vba, autocad

My company used autocad 2009 and a printing Plug-in which was made by VB,they worked perfect.But when my company uses autocad 2010,the problem rises:The printing Plug-in  doesn't work.

Although I downloaded and installed the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Module 32bit (from  http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?siteID=123112&id=12715668&linkID=9240618), the printing Plug-in can not work with autocad 2010.the commands from the plug-in cannot be recognized.

Firstly I install autocad 2010,then VBA,next printing Plug-in.Is there anything wrong?

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439061/autocad-2010-doesnt-support-vb-developed-plug-in  There are some answers that can help.  Also see the comments about AutoCAD VBA support being deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the module in the startup collection in APPLOAD ?