# autocad 2010 doesn't support VB developed plug-in

Tags: vba, autocad

I have encountered a problem. My company bought a VB developed plug-in,which allows us to print the dwg files to a shared printer.This plug-in works fine with version 2009 and before. Instead of tapping 'plot' in command window, we tap  'eplot' ,the plug-in would then connect to the remote printer,upload,print and back up the dwg files.

But after we upgraded to 2010,the problem arose. The 'eplot'  command wasn't  being recognized by 2010. I had heard that 2010 doesn't support VBA applications, but after downloading the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Module , the situation didn't improve. The Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Module is installed before the plug-in.

..

Could anyone give me a hand?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Because MS is dropping VBA support, Autodesk is phasing out support for VBA add on in AutoCAD.  The answers below should get you working on AcadCAD 2010.  But you may need to buy .NET, AutoLISP or ObjectARX developed plug-in to keep working in AutoCAD versions after AutoCAD 2010  (http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Visual-Basic-Customization/No-more-VBA-in-2010-What-do-us-utility-programming-drafters-do/td-p/2508713/page/4)

Answer (score 2):

Have you gone through the steps from this [AutoDesk Support Page](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/ps/dl/item?linkID=9240617&id=12900036&siteID=123112). It describes some additional steps other than just downloading the VBA runtime if you are in an enterprise environment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a 32/64bit problem?

Installing VBA components on a 64 bit ACAD system might work, but the VBA component might do some unexpexted things during runtime.

So, is your 2010 ACAD a 64bit system? If so, you could test this behaviour on a 32bit ACAD 2010 system.